# I don't see the line number while debugging a package (BPL)

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a package (T_LibR280.dpk) that installs some IDE experts.
I have a crash in that package and I try to debug it.
The problem is that I don't see the line where the crash happens:

```
[41666AFF]{T_LibR280.bpl} xyz.BaseForm.FormShow + $8B //No line no.
[651BA259]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.DoShow (Line 4564, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $14
```

The package is compiled in Debug mode. All settings seem correct:
[image]
[image]

The MAP files is present next to the BPL file. Maybe the IDE is looking for it in a different place?
Update: The [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Package_Files_Created_by_Compiling) says: "You can discard the RSM file. You do not need a package debug symbol file to debug packages".

Comment: I worked once. I thought the "Debug information" was necessary. For normal projects, this is not necessary. Here is needed, probably because the BPL is an "external" module. Anyway, after a Delphi restart, again it won't work. I don't see an RSM file for my BPL.

Comment: Try EurekaLog - it should be able to tell you the source line of the exception.

Comment: @IVOGELOV - In a package running in the IDE?

Comment: Does not matter where the package is running.

Comment: Have you tried ticking the "Use Debug .dcus" in the Debugging section of the configuration?

Comment: @mait - That setting is for something else. And if you look at the two lines I quoted in my question, you will see that the debug information is already present in the VCL code. The problem I have is not with the VCL code.